# assign button press to evoke a new page from sliding menu

Tags: android

I've implemented a sliding menu android framework by following a [tutorial video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YeR7McJIltk), the menu works well but I can't figure out how to make the buttons generate new "fresh", i.e. distinct, pages wherein I can place subsequent components/"activities".

Right now all the buttons do is "toggle" back and forth between having the menu exposed, and hiding the menu, making visible the complete "landing page".

This is how it looks:

[image]

[image]

In my layout file, I think this is responsible for assigning functionality to the buttons:

```
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="Button 1" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="Button 2"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="toggleMenu"
        android:text="Button 3" />
```

So as you can see the buttons evoke the method `toggleMenu` which looks like this:

```
public void toggleMenu() {
    switch (this.menuCurrentState){
        case CLOSED:
            this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.OPENING;
            this.menu.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            this.menuAnimatonScroller.startScroll(0, 0, this.getMenuWidth(),
                    0, menuAnimationDuration);
            break;
        case OPEN:
            this.menuCurrentState = MenuState.CLOSING;
            this.menuAnimatonScroller.startScroll(this.currentContentOffset,
                    0, -this.currentContentOffset, 0, menuAnimationDuration);
            break;
        default:
            return;
    }

    this.menuAnimationHandler.postDelayed(this.menuAnimationRunnable, menuAnimationPollingInterval);

    this.invalidate();
}
```

I guess I need to make a new method for generating fresh pages and then assign that to the button push rather than toggle menu, I've tried this a few times using `intent` but I've not been able to quite figure it out.

What do I need to account for in such an operation?

How should such a function look?

The complete code can be found on [my github page](https://github.com/h1395010/Fish_Balls).

Thank you for your consideration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

dig this tutorial, it's one of the only helpful ones, in my opinion:
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-activity-from-one-screen-to-another-screen/

or check the pertinent info below"

1. XML Layouts
   Create following two XML layout files in “res/layout/” folder :

res/layout/main.xml – Represent screen 1
res/layout/main2.xml – Represent screen 2
File : res/layout/main.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I&apos;m screen 1 (main.xml)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click me to another screen" />
```

File : res/layout/main2.xml

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="I&apos;m screen 2 (main2.xml)"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
```

2. Activities
Create two activity classes :

AppActivity.java –> main.xml
App2Activity.java –> main2.xml
To navigate from one screen to another screen, use following code :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, anotherActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

File : AppActivity.java

package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class AppActivity extends Activity {

```
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton() {

    final Context context = this;

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(context, App2Activity.class);
                        startActivity(intent);   

        }

    });

}
```

}
File : App2Activity.java

package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

public class App2Activity extends Activity {

```
Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main2);
}
```

}
3. AndroidManifest.xml
Declares above two activity classes in AndroidManifest.xml.

File : AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".AppActivity" >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:name=".App2Activity" >
    </activity>
</application>
```